# FQL - Order photos in album by like_count

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the photos of a *Facebook* album ordered by like count in *FQL* with a this query:

```
SELECT like_info, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid="xxxxxxxxxx_xxxx" ORDER BY like_info.like_count desc
```

But I get an error `(#602) like_count is not a member of the like_info scalar.`

```
SELECT like_info, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid="xxxxxxxxxx_xxxx" ORDER BY like_info desc
```

Does the trick, but I don't know why: isn't *like_info* an object? it is possible to order a query using a member of an object?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, [similar bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238572709578508) have been reported and supposedly fixed.

Comment: Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: I would create a bugreport on facebook's site, and see they take on it, but I guess you could save every picture and order them on your application site, but that is not what the question was for.

Comment: If the album has quite a lot of photos this is probably not too practical, though

Answer (score 2):

Just use ORDER BY like_info. Don't forget to put LIMIT, otherwise query might crash for large number of pics:

```
SELECT like_info, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid="20531316728_324257" ORDER BY like_info desc LIMIT 10
```

[Run in Facebook API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20like_info,%20object_id%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20aid=%2220531316728_324257%22%20ORDER%20BY%20like_info%20desc%20LIMIT%2010)